# Spring Boot setting up Active profiles in an environment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, configuration, spring-boot

I have a couple of Linux Environments into which my spring boot application is going to be deployed i.e QA & PROD.

If I set a System property such as thsese and pull them in the Spring Boot app to set the active environments,

```
ENVIRONMENT=QA in QA and
ENVIRONMENT=PROD in PROD
```

are there any potential limitations (technicnal, administration, continuous integration issues etc.)that I might face or is there a better approach to pick up the active environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just name your environment variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` and it will automatically get picked up by Spring Boot, no need to implement any custom logic for that (see the documentation about externalized configuration: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config).

Comment: Is this the right syntax for multiple active profiles? SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production,profileA,profileB

Comment: also http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-profiles which explains the concept of profiles. @uhsarp yes